# Translation: confabulation

Tags: translation

How is **confabulation** properly translated into Chinese?

Wikipedia doesn't have a corresponding entry.

The only dictionary I can find this in, LDC English-Chinese Wordlist, just lists **交谈/闲谈** - which is not nearly specific enough.

JSYK, Wikipedia defines confabulation as:

> In psychology, confabulation (verb: confabulate) is a memory disturbance, defined as the production of fabricated, distorted or misinterpreted memories about oneself or the world, without the conscious intention to deceive.[1]

**Edit:** the meaning I'm looking for this this:

> (psychology) A fabricated memory believed to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

虚构 or perhaps 虚构症 if you want to be clear that it is a diagnosis. 虚谈症 is another option.

Comment: Yeah I saw that on baidu aswell but doesn't really seem to be the *right* word

Comment: Variations given: Confabulation is an important type of false memory / 虚构是虚假记忆的重要类型之一 | Phantastic confabulation / 幻想性虚谈症

Comment: That is the best translation there is. i prefer no translation at all. George IV had an episode of -, when he believed he was at the battle of Waterloo.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `虚构记忆` as in `fabricated memory`?

Or `错构症`, `虚谈症` according to [this](http://hospital.kingnet.com.tw/library/diagnose.html?lid=2059) ([simplified Chinese](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=zh-CN&js=y&prev=_t&hl=zh-TW&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhospital.kingnet.com.tw%2Flibrary%2Fdiagnose.html%3Flid%3D2059&edit-text=&act=url)).